# Do I need to file a tax return if I am a nonfiler college student?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tuition, student, scholarship

I am a college student and since I started college, I put down as a non-filer on FAFSA. This year I am about to turn 24 and I keep receiving a 1098-t, but I don't have any income nor have I ever had a job and my tuition is paid through a grant and a scholarship.

I was wondering if I have to file taxes or I don't?

Comment: do your parents or somebody else count you as a dependent?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep no i am not a dependent on my parents taxes for fasfa i put that they dont file which is a nonfiler and i have never had a job.

Answer (score 3):

Your tax-free scholarship is tax free as long as you spend it on the specified expenses. Any amounts spent on other expenses is taxable, and should be reported on a form 1040. From [this page](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc421):

Scholarships, fellowship grants, and other grants are tax-free if you meet the following conditions:

> - You're a candidate for a degree at an educational institution that maintains a regular faculty and curriculum and normally has a
>   regularly enrolled body of students in attendance at the place where
>   it carries on its educational activities; and
> - The amounts you receive are used to pay for tuition and fees required for enrollment or attendance at the educational institution,
>   or for fees, books, supplies, and equipment required for courses at
>   the educational institution.
>
> **Taxable**
>
> You must include in gross income:
>
> - Amounts used for incidental expenses, such as room and board, travel, and optional equipment.
> - Amounts received as payments for teaching, research, or other services required as a condition for receiving the scholarship or
>   fellowship grant. However, you don't need to include in gross income
>   any amounts you receive for services that are required by the National
>   Health Service Corps Scholarship Program, the Armed Forces Health
>   Professions Scholarship and Financial Assistance Program, or a
>   comprehensive student work-learning-service program (as defined in
>   section 448(e) of the Higher Education Act of 1965) operated by a work
>   college.

Here is a [survey process on the IRS websit](https://www.irs.gov/help/ita/do-i-include-my-scholarship-fellowship-or-education-grant-as-income-on-my-tax-return)e to use if you're not sure.

If you are a dependent on someone's tax return, and the taxable amount of your scholarship/grant income is more than the threshold for that year (in 2022: $ 1,150) then you are [required to file a tax return](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p501).  If you're not a dependent, then the threshold amount in 2022 is $ 12,950 (per that same page).

Comment: Thanks for the great edit mhoran_psprep!